# angular Jasmine karma error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clear')

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am getting error in a jasmin karma test case

> 20 07 2022 13:55:13.316:ERROR [Chrome 103.0.5060.114 (Windows 10) | MemberPrTableComponent | should addClicked()]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clear')
> at MemberPrFormPaginatorComponent.loadComponent (main.js:148971:19)
> at MemberPrFormPaginatorComponent.ngOnInit (src/app/member/member-pr-form-paginator/member-pr-form-paginator.component.ts:36:5)

The code is

```
addClicked() {
    this.formService.currentPR = null;
    this.modalService.show(MemberPrFormPaginatorComponent, {class: 'modal-dialog modal-lg'});
  }
```

The test case i have written is

```
fit('should addClicked()', () => {
    const modelService = TestBed.get(BsModalService);
    let obj : MemberPrFormPaginatorComponent;
    component.addClicked();
    spyOn(modelService, 'show()').and.callFake(() => {
      return of({});
    });
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    expect(modelService).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

**BsModelService**

```
    import { ComponentRef, TemplateRef, EventEmitter, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentLoaderFactory } from 'ngx-bootstrap/component-loader';
import { ModalBackdropComponent } from './modal-backdrop.component';
import { ModalOptions } from './modal-options.class';
import { BsModalRef } from './bs-modal-ref.service';
import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
export declare class BsModalService {
    private clf;
    private modalDefaultOption;
    config: ModalOptions;
    onShow: EventEmitter<any>;
    onShown: EventEmitter<any>;
    onHide: EventEmitter<any>;
    onHidden: EventEmitter<any>;
    protected isBodyOverflowing: boolean;
    protected originalBodyPadding: number;
    protected scrollbarWidth: number;
    protected backdropRef?: ComponentRef<ModalBackdropComponent>;
    private _backdropLoader;
    private modalsCount;
    private lastDismissReason?;
    private loaders;
    private _renderer;
    constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2, clf: ComponentLoaderFactory, modalDefaultOption: ModalOptions);
    /** Shows a modal */
    show<T>(content: string | TemplateRef<any> | {
        new (...args: any[]): T;
    }, config?: ModalOptions<T>): BsModalRef<T>;
    hide(id?: number | string): void;
    _showBackdrop(): void;
    _hideBackdrop(): void;
    _showModal<T>(content: any): BsModalRef<T>;
    _hideModal(id?: number | string): void;
    getModalsCount(): number;
    setDismissReason(reason: string): void;
    removeBackdrop(): void;
    /** Checks if the body is overflowing and sets scrollbar width */
    /** @internal */
    checkScrollbar(): void;
    setScrollbar(): void;
    private resetScrollbar;
    private getScrollbarWidth;
    private _createLoaders;
    private removeLoaders;
    private copyEvent;
    static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<BsModalService, [null, null, { optional: true; }]>;
    static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<BsModalService>;
}
```

can someone tell me where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: I suspect that whatever `this.modalService.show()` does throws that error. With your current test case, you're only testing if the service method was called, so you may aswell mock the service.

Comment: @Mike S Updated the modelService